# Flask + WTForms: updating a row

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask, wtforms

I try to update an existing row in the database. When I submit the form I'm directed to /item/edit/ which triggers a 404. I have similar code in a different project and that works correctly. I can't figure what is wrong with this.

```
@main.route('/item/edit/<string:url>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_item(url):
  i = get_item_by_url(url)
  form = ItemForm(obj=i)
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    i.title = form.title.data
    i.url = form.url.data
    i.body = form.body.data
    i.email = form.email.data
    i.private = form.private.data
    file = request.files['itempic']
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
      filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
      file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
      i.itempic = filename
    db.session.add(i)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('The Item: %s, has been updated succesfully.' % form.url.data)
    return redirect(url_for("index"))
  return render_template('/item/edit.html',
    form = form,
    i = i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your method is mapped to `/item/edit/something-here` and `something-here` will be mapped to the `url` variable.

When you request just `/item/edit/` it doesn't map to anything so it raises a 404.

Comment: your form submission should go to something like `{{ url_for('edit_item',url="whatever") }}`